# Jquery TokenInput Initial Strings Search

Tags: javascript, jquery-tokeninput

Im using jquery Tokeninput library for autocomplete functionality. Im currently struggling with the issue I have with the search results. When I type something, it returns all the words for characters which are being typed. I want it to only return the search results where initial strings match.

For example, if I type "Na", it returns all the words which have "**Na**" such as "Ca**na**da", "Fi**na**ncial" etc.

I would ONLY like for it to return words which start with "**Na**" such as "**Na**tion", "**Na**scar" etc.

Im new to JavaScript to facing trouble updating this script. Can someone please help ?

Here is the library that Im using - https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput/blob/master/src/jquery.tokeninput.js

```
    $("#demo-input").tokenInput([
  {id: 7, name: "Canada"},
  {id: 11, name: "Financial "},
  {id: 13, name: "Nation"},
  {id: 17, name: "Nascar"},
  {id: 19, name: "USA"},
  {id: 31, name: "Economics"}
]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked library code and I don't think you can pass any option to change default search type which checks for existence of search query within a value. However, I found a heck which you could use (IMO **you shouldn't unless necessary**).

Working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/611422/)

Library allows you to process search results by using `onResult` and `onCachedResult` callbacks you could use that for your leverage.

```
$("#demo-input").tokenInput([
  {id: 7, name: "Canada"},
  {id: 11, name: "Financial "},
  {id: 13, name: "Nation"},
  {id: 17, name: "Nascar"},
  {id: 19, name: "USA"},
  {id: 31, name: "Economics"}
], 
{
    onResult: filterSearchResults,
    onCachedResult: filterSearchResults
});

function filterSearchResults(items){
    var query = $("#demo-input").parent().find("ul li input").val().toLowerCase();
    return items.filter(i => i.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(query));
}
```